# jQuery Datatables bug in column width

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm working on a project, where i'm having trouble with the column width of a jQuery Datatable.

[image: Table]

When i remove the first header row, the table displays as it should. But with the extra header row, the table columns width got messed up.

Why does this happen? And offcourse the most important; How can i solve it?

**Initialization:**

```
datatable = $('.datatable').DataTable({
    "stateSave": true,
    "scrollX": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "order": [],
    "buttons": [
        {extend: 'excel', text: '<i class="fa fa-table fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>'},
        {extend: 'colvis', text: '<i class="fa fa-columns fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>'},
        {text: '<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>', className: 'buttons-refresh', action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
            dt.order([]).draw();
            window.location.reload();
        }}
    ],
    "dom": '<lfB<t>pi>',
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box-body">
    <table class="datatable table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6" style="border-bottom: 0px;"></th>
                @foreach (getMonths() as $month)
                    <th colspan="2" style="border-bottom: 0px; text-align: center;">{{ $month }} {{ year() }}</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Werknaam</th>
                <th>Opdrachtgever</th>
                <th>Aanneemsom</th>
                <th>MMW</th>
                <th>Totaal</th>
                @foreach (getMonths() as $month)
                    <th>Prognose</th>
                    <th>Werkelijk</th>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($projects as $project)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $project->number }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $project->client->name ?? '- geen relatie -' }}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;">{!! format_currency($project->contract_sum, '') !!}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;">{!! format_currency($project->contract_variations, '') !!}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right;">{!! format_currency($project->total, '') !!}</td>
                    @foreach (getMonths() as $m => $month)
                        <td style="text-align: right;" class="text-primary">
                            {!! format_currency($project->amounts->where('year', year())->where('month', $m)->sum('prognosis_amount'), '') !!}
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;" class="text-success">
                            {!! format_currency($project->amounts->where('year', year())->where('month', $m)->sum('actual_amount'), '') !!}
                        </td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
table.datatable {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.datatable th, .datatable td { 
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > thead > tr > th {
    padding: 8px 13px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Hello friend. You're going to have a lot more luck getting an answer if you make a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means simplify your code to it's simplest parts, and make a fiddle. But I guarantee by the time you do that you will solve your own problem.

Comment: Thx, fixed it indeed. removed `table.datatable { table-layout: fixed; }`. But now the widths are different on each page. -_-'

Comment: Are you referring to the text in 2nd and 3rd column which are overlapping? I wouldn't mess with Datatables css, it is pretty good by itself already

Comment: @Yuri Sorry, I don't understand your question? I didn't changed to much of it's CSS. Table is correctly formatted. I removed the table layout CSS property and now the problem is fixed. The only problem I have now is that the columns do not have the same width on every page.